# SQl - How to grab duplicate records where they are within 7 days of each other

Tags: sql

I have a table where there are two columns. Account Number and Date.

I want to be able to be able to grab all the duplicate account numbers where the date is within 7 days of each other.

For example, my first record would be would have the account number 123456 and the date of 2020-04-21. I want to grab that record only if there is another record with the account number 123456 and the date is within 7 days of 2020-04-21. If it is not then skip that record and continue to the next record until it goes through the entire table.

Im not too sure which direction to take to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can join the table to itself and end up with something like this:

**untested**

```
select T1.AccountNumber, T1.Date DateT1, T2.Date DateT2
from YourTable T1
inner join YourTable T2
   on T1.AccountNumber = T2.AccountNumber
   and T1.Date <= T2.Date
   and T1.Date > dateadd("dd", -7, T2.Date)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: This doesn't actually do what was asked. If `T1.Date` is less than `T2.Date` -7 days then it will ONLY produce results where `T1.Date` was exactly 7 days before `T2.Date`rather than "within 7 days" as asked. Also, by the notion of this, `T1.Date` is always going to be less than `T2.Date`, so `AND T1.Date <= T2.Date` isn't doing anything extra and can be removed. but still, this doesn't work as a whole script. Tested and it produces 0 results,

Comment: @Simon  Thank you.  I did bold that this was untested.  I messed up `<` and `>`.  I have changed my answer -- the last line is now `and T1.Date > dateadd("dd", -7, T2.Date)`.  There are many ways to specify "within 7 days".  Could use `datediff`, `dateadd` on either date, `between`.

Answer (score 1):

Working on SQL-Server (as per your original tag);

**Assumptive table structure**

```sql
CREATE TABLE trans (Idx INT IDENTITY(1,1), accountnumber VARCHAR(6), tdate DATE)
```

**Data as per your question**

```sql
INSERT INTO trans (accountnumber, tdate)
VALUES ('123456', '2020-04-21'),
('654321', '2020-04-21'),
('123456', '2020-04-19').
('654321', '2020-04-22')
```

Now there is a table and some data to work with.

Now to **output** your results, you would need to first select your table

```sql
SELECT * FROM trans a
```

Next you would use an `INNER JOIN` back to the same table.

Joining by `a.accountnumber = b.accountnumber` SQL will remove any results that don't have an exact match

```sql
INNER JOIN trans b ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
```

Then in order to get only the results within 7 days you can use `between` and using the date in table `a` apply a `DATEDIFF -7` and `DATEDIFF +7` to get 7 days either side of the transaction.

```sql
b.tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-7,a.tdate) AND DATEADD(d,7,a.tdate)
```

And lastly, to avoid duplicates, make sure the transactions only return a result that hasn't already been checked by using the following.

```sql
AND b.Idx > a.Idx
```

This will avoid duplicates such as;

```sql
Account tDate1      tDate2
123456  2020-04-21  2020-04-19
123456  2020-04-19  2020-04-21
```

But it will also allow transactions to be picked up if, for some bizarre reason, the "first transaction" was actually after the "second transaction". Like in my example data.

Put this all together and it looks something like this;

```sql
SELECT
    a.AccountNumber,
    a.Idx [Transaction a ID],
    a.tdate [Transaction a Date],
    b.Idx [Transaction b ID],
    b.tdate [Transaction b Date]
FROM trans a
INNER JOIN trans b
    ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
    AND b.tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-7,a.tdate) AND DATEADD(d,7,a.tdate)
    AND b.Idx > a.Idx
```

Hope this helps, here's some links to help clarify this all.

- [Using INNER JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)
- [DATEDIFF function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)
- [SQL BETWEEN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

If you are using a different SQL instance, such as MySQL, please let us know so we can rework the correct answer.

Good luck!

Comment: *Probably* don't want to interval + or - 7 days -- that will just produce duplicate sets.

Comment: Thanks @avery_larry, I hadn't accounted for those duplicates. Answer edited to take care of those.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed your correctly, you can use `exists` for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.account_number = t.account_number
        and t1.date >= t.date - interval '7' day
        and t1.date <  t.date
)
```

You did not tell which database you are running: the above query uses standard ANSI SQL date syntax - which not all databases support. You might need to adapt the syntax for your database.

It is also quite unclear what you mean by *within 7 days*. This checks if a record exists with the same `account_number` during the preceding 7 days; you might want to adjust that too according to *your definition* of "within 7 days".